# Is there an online editor for creating persisted and connected markdown documents?

Tags: markdown

There are plenty of useful online editors for the markdown language.

However, is there any that allows to easily create a bunch of persisted and connected markdown pages?

By *persisted*, I mean that whatever documents you are working on would be saved by the editor (e.g. the markdown editor of github will persist any edits to a git project).

By *connected*, I mean that it should be easy to not only link to other markdown pages (which can just be a link such as `[page2](page2.html)` but also to easily create new pages to be linked.

Comment: I'd love to have this, also with: 1) support for MathJax, and 2) Free hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I use

#### http://jottit.com

very basic, but could be a start.

Comment: That is a nice tool. I can see you can write Markdown and publish it as a webpage (as far as I can see, it is possible to edit the published webpage too). Actually, I forgot about this question and I have also toyed around with my own simple implementation for which I will put the link in another answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create and store it at [**github:gist**](https://gist.github.com/), just give it a filename with the extension .md and it will render as markdown.

Comment: Thanks that is a great tip! Is there a way to access the markdown files as HTML (I only managed to see the rendered git embedded in the github webpage). What would be the best approach to link from one gist to the other (again, ideally without having to go through the github interface) (example files here https://gist.github.com/4081435)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across another possible solution:

[Commonplace](http://helloform.com/projects/commonplace/)

> A simple server for Markdown files. Allows to create and edit Markdown file using a wiki-like web interface.

And yet another:

[WCM](http://woffs.de/Software/WCM)

> WofFS' Content Machine is a tiny perl CGI which takes a directory tree of Markdown files or shell scripts (or whatever) and turns it into a browsable website.

[Docbase](http://appbaseio.github.io/Docbase/)

> Turn markdown files into a beautiful documentation hub.